# Worklight 6.2 custom client side log collection

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

We want to be able to collect and centralise client logs in worklight console. (WL v6.2)

To my understanding, we can create a Log Profile in Worklight console, and collected client logs can be viewed there where WL analytics is not used.

As in Guideline 05_12_Remote_controlled_client_side_log_collection.pdf, we can write a `WLClientLogReceiver`. But it didn't provide any detail on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with development server you can review all logs in the Analytics Console, accessible from the Worklight Console.

When working with a production server, you need to implement a WLClientLogeceiver. By "WLClientLogReceiver" it is meant to implement an adapter by that name.

The tutorial is meant to provide the basic premise and information on using client logging. WLClientLogReceiver is fruther explained in detail and with implementation examples in the user documentation topic [Server preparation for uploaded log data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_uploaded_client_log_data.html).

If you read all of the documentation linked above by Idan I believe all of your questions will be answered.

Basically, when the Worklight server receives logs from the client it will send them to Operational Analytics AND it will send them to WLClientLogReceiver's log procedure. The implementation of this log procedure will determine the destination of the uploaded log content. In other words, this is how you can configure where your log data will be sent if you are not using IBM's Operational Analytics offering.

Comment: So in other words, i can add extra handling / logging. But ultimately. Analytics Console has to be used for logging purpose? And also do you mean i can't use built-in .WAR for production? Thank you!

Comment: 1) Analytics will provide you all sort of data extrapolated for incoming data. 2) In production, the recommendation is to use a separate server for analytics, unless you're running a super-computer there with endless resources. Please review the Analytics user documentation for more information on both topics.

Comment: Thank you so much. If what i want is to gather client custom logs / debug messages for production environment. is Analytics Platform the right tool?

Comment: That is the tool the IBM provides for this purpose. If you have another tool, you can try to integrate with it instead.

Comment: I am still not so clear. So if i want to use analytics, i should install that WAR and config server setting. The main purpose of overriding WLClientLogReceiver is for third-party integration. is it correct? thanks!@Idan Adar

Comment: You are not overriding it. You are adding it by implementing it because it does not exist by default. There is no third-party integration involved here.

Comment: Sorry. maybe this is stupid question. If i implement it and return true. then analytics is not needed? where are logs collected

Comment: You cannot implement this w/out having analytics installed

Comment: You need it if you are using an analytics server

Comment: so whats the purpose to implement WLClientLogReceiver? Thank you Idan

Comment: @Leslie, Okay, I will need to update my answer with fuller details. I'll get back to you when I have the complete picture, it may take some time as Christmas is here and many are not available at this time.

Comment: Thank you for your work Idan. Sorry to keep asking(maybe stupid questions.) Wish you a merry christmas:)

Comment: Hey Leslie. I have updated the answer with a bit more information about WLClientLogReceiver. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks wright8191! i have read documents and seen those contents you posted. But its quite confusing, such as "log procedure will determine the destination of the uploaded log content" but there is analytics settings in server/conf/worklight.properties for path to dedicated analytic service. Ok. So if i stick with Analytics, WLClientLogReceiver is not needed. right?

Comment: I believe that WLClientLogReceiver was the solution to capturing logs before we offered Operational Analytics, and since they now both exist I think that is the source of your confusion.

But you are correct if you are using Analytics, WLClientLogReceiver is not needed.

Comment: And just to clarify "log procedure will determine the destination of the uploaded content" - this means if you create a WLClientLogReceiver adapter with a procedure log, then it will send those logs to wherever you configured the adapter to (i.e. the domain and port defined in the adapter XML)

Comment: As you are online, please let me take this opportunity to clarify my misunderstanding. 1. Analytics is the only IBM tool for gathering client logs in Worklight? 2. Is that Log profile refines logs that will be collected by analytics? Thank you.

Comment: Analytics is not the only tool for gathering client logs. The WLClientLogReceiver adapter allows you to send your client logs to any server of your choosing where you can gather your client logs. As far as the second question, I am a little confused could you try rewording?

Comment: Sorry. For first question. Is it the only thing IBM provided within Worklight. (We are not gonna implement our own, we are exploring. My supervisor said he remember he saw logs collected and seen in "Log profile" page). For second, there are plenty of settings you can change for a log profile, does it affect Analytics? I have tried to change log level from ERROR to DEBUG of a log profile. But it didn't react instantly, its like after 2 or 3 hours then DEBUG levels can be collected. I am not sure the change is the only factor.

Comment: Yes this is the only way to collect client logs provided by Worklight. For your second question, if you are setting the log level it will affect the logs that are captured and sent to Analytics. I am not sure why you saw a delay in the affect, I am not entirely familiar with those settings and they may require a server restart. If you have any further questions related to log capture it would be more fruitful for you to ask a new StackOverflow question. That way other people can benefit, and the US offices are almost entirely out for Holiday, but IBMers from other offices will be checking in.